# How to proof that adjacency matrices of DAG can be permuted to triangular matrices?

Tags: graph-theory, directed-graphs

I've come across the statement that the adjacency matrices of directed acyclic digraphs can always be permuted in such a way that we get a triangular matrix. Although I think I kind of get why, I am unsure how to prove the statement formally.

I have seen the following post: [Directed acyclic graph and adjacency matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1475053/directed-acyclic-graph-and-adjacency-matrix) Unfortunately it's still not clear to me.

Does anyone have a tipp for me?

Comment: Do you understand the notion of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting mentioned in the accepted answer?

Comment: I think so. I also understand that this statement makes sense, but I'm struggling with a formal proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the graph is a DAG, there exists a topological ordering on the vertices. After relabelling the vertices with this ordering, we have labelled vertices $v_1, v_2, \cdots, v_n$ such that if $v_i v_j$ is a directed edge, then $i < j$.

Now, entry $A_{ij}$ of the adjacency matrix is nonzero when there is an edge from $v_i$ to $v_j$. We want to show that $A$ is an (upper) triangular matrix. Formally, this means its entries below the main diagonal are zero. Moreover, entries $A_{ij}$ below the main diagonal are precisely the elements with $i > j$. Can you put it all together now?